# Using EntityFrameworkCore 3 in a .NET Core Class Library with COM hosting enabled throws configuration error

Tags: .net, com, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have created a simple .NET Core class library and have exposed a class to COM using the following article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com

The class library uses EntityFrameworkCore 3 to lookup values in a SQL Server database and return an array of strings.

When I attempt to call the method that does the database lookup inside the .NET Core dll from a Win32 application using COM, the following error is raised by the calling application:

```
Run-time error '-2146233088 (80131500)':

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.

 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to read the configuration section for enclave providers. Make sure the section is correctly formatted in your application configuration file. Error Message: Configuration system failed to initialize

 ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize

 ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.

   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)

   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)

   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_ConfigPaths()

   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String configPath)

   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
```

This error does not occur if I downgrade EntityFrameworkCore to 2.x.  I have tried to create configuration files for both the .NET Core dll and the calling application to try and satisfy the configuration requirements specified in the error, but I have had zero luck.

If anyone has any guidance for me on how to resolve this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It look like a config file is no correctly formatted. It can also be machine.config etc. You could use a tool such a Process Monitor (procmon) from sysinternals to check what are the config files your program hits.

Comment: I thought that too, but I tried with an empty config file to make sure and the error still occurs.  It only happens when calling the DLL through COM.  I can call the .NET Core DLL from another .NET app with no issue.

Comment: there"s not only one config file involved